# Library is throwing an uncaught error during jasmine test in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing

I have the following function:

```
var fs = require('fs');


function Writer(path, content) {
    this.path = path;
    this.content = content;

    this.process = function () {

    fs.writeFile(
        this.path,
        this.content,
        function (error) {
            if (error) {
                throw new Error('Something went wrong during writing');
            }
    }, 'utf-8')

};
}
module.exports = Writer;
```

With the this test:

```
it('test if writing fails ', function () {
    var writer = new Writer(
        '/data/configurations/ab/ba/abba/test.json',
        'content'
    );

    expect(function() {
        writer.process()
    }).toThrowError("Something went wrong during writing");
})
```

So this is expected to fail because there is no file to write. Then the library FS is throwing an Error which is uncaught.
Here is the output from the test:

```
Started
.....F

Failures:
1) writer test test if writing fails 
  Message:
    Expected function to throw an Error.
  Stack:
    Error: Expected function to throw an Error.
        at Object.<anonymous> (/vagrant/project/tests/utils/file/writerTest.js:42:6)

6 specs, 1 failure
Finished in 0.198 seconds


/vagrant/project/node_modules/mock-fs/lib/binding.js:1060
      throw new FSError('ENOENT', filepath);
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/vagrant/project/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/exit'
    at Binding.<anonymous> (/vagrant/project/node_modules/mock-fs/lib/binding.js:1060:13)
```

so the library is throwing and error and the toThrowError doesn't get it. Does someone have an idea how to solve it or what is my mistake?

Comment: so, basically, the error thrown is not the error expected - which means `function (error) {` isn't ever called, right? does using `.toThrow()` instead make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

When ENOENT is thrown, it means that file or directory is missing.
You are missing 'exit' package probably, so you should install it -

https://www.npmjs.com/package/exit

Run `npm install exit`
And it should fix the issue.

Comment: but isn't the problem that the test is expecting an error to be thrown, an error is being thrown, but the test says that no error was thrown (if that makes sense) - fixing the ENOENT error would mean that no error is thrown, therefore, the expected error will still not be thrown, which is a testing error :p

Comment: Thanks, I guess I solved it. I need to parse a callback function into the .process() method and then I can test it. I will give an update. Thanks already for your help!